# Python 3.5 tkinter: resizing widgets to window

Tags: python, tkinter, resize, grid-layout

I am reading, reading and reading but still unable to find the appropriate answer to my issue. I plan to create a 'Masterwindow' in which I implement several frames (currently a Navigation Panel to the left, a 'RootFrame', which shows up, when no process is running, a Statusbar at the bottom, which is for alerts and processings and a main frame. Running the Code below, everything just works fine, but the Frames do not adjust to the resize of the window.

Now, I know, I need to do some sticking in main- and subclasses and set grid_column- and rowconfigure to a weight of >0 but still nothing happens.

I cannot see the reason why. What am I missing? Do I need to put everything in another masterframe?? which I stick to the masterwindow? that can't be right since I am inheriting Frames everywhere...

Thanks for your effort and Input. rgds

p.s: oh by the way: can any1 tell me how to iterate through the rows in a grid method so that I can just simply say 'grid the widget in the next row' (relative) and dont have to use absolute integers?

```
    # -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

    import tkinter.ttk
    from tkinter import *


    class MainApplication(tkinter.Frame):
        @classmethod
        def main(cls):
            root = tkinter.Tk()
            app = cls(root)
            app.master.title('Sample')
            root.resizable(True, True)
            root.mainloop()

        def __init__(self, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
            tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
            self.grid(sticky=N+E+S+W)

            # Var-Declaration
            self.h = 600
            self.w = 1200
            self.widget_fr_opts = dict(relief='groove', borderwidth=1, bg='#EFEFFB')

            #  Widget-Creation
            self.rootframe = RootFrame(self)
            self._visible_ = self.rootframe  # internal updater what frame is visible - starting with rootframe on init
            self.statusbar = Statusbar(self)
            self.navbar = Navbar(self)
            self.main_db = MainDB(self)

            #  Widget-Design

            # Widget-Arrangement
            self.grid_rowconfigure(0, minsize=self.h * 0.95)
            self.grid_rowconfigure(1, minsize=self.h * 0.05)
            self.grid_columnconfigure(0, minsize=self.w*0.15)
            self.grid_columnconfigure(1, minsize=self.w*0.85)
            self.navbar.grid(sticky=N+S+E+W, column=0, row=0)
            self.main_db.grid(sticky=N+E+S+W, column=1, row=0)
            self.rootframe.grid(sticky=N+E+S+W, column=1, row=0)
            self.statusbar.grid(sticky=W+E, column=0, columnspan=2, row=1)

            self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
            self.statusbar.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
            self.rootframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
            self.main_db.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

            self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
            self.navbar.rowconfigure(4, weight=1)
            self.rootframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
            self.main_db.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

            self.rootframe.lift(self.main_db)

        def visualize(self, master):
            """Lifts master to upper Level"""
            master.lift(self.rootframe)
            self._visible_ = master

        def event_handler(self):
            pass

        def start_subapp(self, app):
            self.visualize(app)
            app.activate_content()


    class RootFrame(tkinter.Frame):
        """General Launcher Frame as a Placeholder"""

        def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
            tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)

            #  Var-Daclaration
            self.widget_fr_opts = dict(relief='sunken', borderwidth=1)
            self.widget_grid_opts = dict(sticky=N+E+S+W, padx=1, pady=1)

            #  Widget-Creation
            self.Image = tkinter.ttk.Label(self, text='there would be a centered image right here', anchor='center')

            #  Widget-Design
            self.configure(**self.widget_fr_opts)

            #  Widget-Arrangement
            self.Image.grid(column=0, row=0, **self.widget_grid_opts)

            self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
            self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)


    class Navbar(tkinter.Frame):
        """vertical NavBar"""

        def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
            tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)

            #  Var-Daclaration
            self._info_ = tkinter.StringVar()
            self.widget_fr_opts = dict(relief='groove', borderwidth=1)
            self.widget_grid_opts = dict(sticky=N+E+S+W, padx=1, pady=1)
            self.widget_grid_subopts = dict(sticky=W+N+E, padx=1, pady=1)
            self._statusbar = parent.statusbar

            #  Widget-Creation
            self._info_.set('Menu:\n...Menusentences:')
            self.TextInfo = tkinter.ttk.Label(self, textvariable=self._info_)
            self.Btn_Progress = tkinter.ttk.Button(self, text='Start Progress',
                                                   command=lambda: self.statusbar_input('Starting progress ...'))   # some code being started
            self.Btn_Database = tkinter.ttk.Button(self, text='Database',
                                                   command=lambda: parent.start_subapp(parent.main_db))  # Database window is lifted and content initialized
            self.Btn_Exit = tkinter.ttk.Button(self, text='Exit', command=parent.quit)

            #  Widget-Design
            self.configure(**self.widget_fr_opts)

            #  Widget-Arrangement
            self.TextInfo.grid(column=0, row=1, **self.widget_grid_subopts)
            self.Btn_Progress.grid(column=0, row=2, **self.widget_grid_subopts)
            self.Btn_Database.grid(column=0, row=3, **self.widget_grid_subopts)
            self.Btn_Exit.grid(column=0, row=4, **self.widget_grid_subopts)

            self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
            self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=0)
            self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=0)
            self.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=0)
            self.grid_rowconfigure(3, weight=0)
            self.grid_rowconfigure(4, weight=0)

        def statusbar_input(self, comm: str):
            self._statusbar.start()
            self._statusbar._info_.set(comm)


    class Statusbar(tkinter.Frame):
        """Status-Bar at the bottom"""

        def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
            tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)

            #  Var-Daclaration
            self.prgrvalue = tkinter.IntVar()
            self._info_ = tkinter.StringVar()
            self._user_ = 'some user'
            self.widget_fr_opts = dict(relief='sunken', borderwidth=1)
            self.widget_grid_opts = dict(padx=1, pady=1)
            self.widget_grid_subopts = dict(padx=1, pady=1)  # sticky=W + E,

            #  Widget-Creation
            self._info_.set('Initializing ...')
            self.prgrvalue.set(0)
            self.TextInfo = tkinter.ttk.Label(self, textvariable=self._info_)
            self.UserInfo = tkinter.ttk.Label(self, textvariable=self._user_)
            self.progress_ = tkinter.ttk.Progressbar(self)
            self.Btn_Move = tkinter.ttk.Button(self, text='Move it', command=lambda: self.start())  # just for initial testing, will be removed later
            self.Btn_Stop = tkinter.ttk.Button(self, text='Stop it', command=lambda: self.stop())

            #  Widget-Design
            self.configure(**self.widget_fr_opts)
            self.progress_.configure(length=200, mode='determinate', orient=tkinter.HORIZONTAL)

            #  Widget-Arrangement
            self.progress_.grid(sticky=W+E, column=0, row=0, **self.widget_grid_subopts)
            self.TextInfo.grid(column=1, row=0, **self.widget_grid_subopts)
            self.UserInfo.grid(column=2, row=0, padx=1, pady=1)  # sticky=E,
            self.Btn_Move.grid(column=3, row=0, **self.widget_grid_subopts)
            self.Btn_Stop.grid(column=4, row=0, **self.widget_grid_subopts)
            self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
            self.grid_columnconfigure(1, minsize=200)
            self.grid_columnconfigure(2, minsize=200)

        def start(self):
            # just testing
            self.progress_.start()

        def stop(self):
            # just testing
            self.progress_.stop()


    class MainDB(tkinter.Frame):
        """Frame for visualizing database."""

        def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
            tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)

            #  Var-Daclaration
            self._activated_ = False
            self._source_ = None
            self.combotext = tkinter.StringVar()
            self.combotext.set('Please choose a tab...')
            self.widget_fr_opts = dict(relief='sunken', borderwidth=1)
            self.widget_grid_opts = dict(sticky=N+E+S+W, padx=1, pady=1)

            #  Widget-Creation
            #  CREATION OF TOOLS TO MANIPULATE DATABASE
            self.toolframe = tkinter.Frame(self, width=100, height=50, relief='groove', borderwidth=1)
            self.combo = tkinter.ttk.Combobox(self.toolframe, textvariable=self.combotext)
            # more to come

            #  CREATION OF DATABASE'WINDOW
            self.dbframe = tkinter.Frame(self, width=100, relief='groove', borderwidth=1)
            self.db_treeview = tkinter.ttk.Treeview(self.dbframe, columns=('size', 'modified'), selectmode='extended')
            #  more to come

            #  Widget-Design

            #  Widget-Arrangement
            self.toolframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=N+E+W, padx=1, pady=1)
            self.combo.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=N+E, padx=1, pady=1)
            self.dbframe.grid(column=0, row=1,  sticky=NSEW, padx=1, pady=1)
            self.db_treeview.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=NSEW, padx=1, pady=1)

            self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
            self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=0)
            self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
            self.dbframe.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
            self.dbframe.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1, minsize=600)
            self.toolframe.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
            self.toolframe.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        def activate_content(self):
            #  some contentloading and initializations
            pass

        def db_connector(self, comm: str, save=False) -> bool:
            #  some connection code
            pass


    if __name__ == '__main__':

        UserScreen = MainApplication.main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are neglecting to give a weight to any rows or columns in the root window. Without it, tkinter doesn't know how to allocate extra space when you resize the window.

```
def main(cls):
    ...
    root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

Since you're only putting a single widget in the root window, I recommend using `pack` since  you can accomplish everything in a single line.

```
    self.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```